# Cocoa creating temporary folders/directories for saving the files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Is it possible to create the temporary directories in cocoa application for saving the files temporarily.

As per the scenario I need to process some video files and those files firstly will be converted to thumbnails etc then whose files will be uploaded to server.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: yes, temporary probably means you need to create it and then remove it after processing

Comment: yes, when the processing start for uploading, old files would not be there and does not processed again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the temporary directory is to use [NSTemporaryDirectory()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1409211-nstemporarydirectory)

**Edit**

The above is no longer the approved method of locating the temporary directory. You should now use [[NSFileManager URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407693-urlfordirectory?language=objc).

Comment: This alone is not enough. Matt Gallagher's solution quoted by Parag Bafna is still the most complete approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSTemporaryDirectory()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1409211-nstemporarydirectory?language=objc).

> Returns the path of the temporary directory for the current user.

```
NSString* tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString* bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
tempDir = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:bundleIdentifier];
```

Comment: @uchuugaka check link in the answers (first line). You should check answers carefully before giving down vote.

Comment: ah, sorry. It's still a lot of work, but still necessary to work with the mkstemp family.

Comment: Still the downvote would stay since all this does is reference a link and paste its content, you really ought to add some additional commentary

Comment: It's still valuable to reference that and quote it, but adding commentary, like when to use that, or why. (and when not, such as when sandboxed)